# SBT warns about potentially incompatible Scala versions which don't show up in dependency-graph

Tags: scala, sbt

After `sbt update` I get

```
> update
[info] Updating {file:/home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/scalan-lite/}default-4e7ca5...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-actors;2.10.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] Potentially incompatible versions of dependencies of {file:/home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/scalan-lite/}default-4e7ca5:
[warn]    org.scala-lang: 2.10.3, 2.10.0
```

General advice for this is to use `sbt-dependency-graph`, but it doesn't show any 2.10.0 dependencies:

```
> dependency-tree
[info] com.huawei:scalan-lite_2.10:0.1
[info]   +-com.chuusai:shapeless_2.10.2:2.0.0-M1
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.3
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.3
[info]   | |   +-org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3
[info]   | |   
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3
[info]
```

And there doesn't seem to be anything that depends on `2.10.0` in my dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % "test"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  //"com.chuusai" % "shapeless" % "2.0.0-M1" cross CrossVersion.full
  "com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.10.2" % "2.0.0-M1" // alternatively ...
)

libraryDependencies += "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.10.1" % "test"
```

How can I find where the 2.10.0 dependency comes from?

Comment: If I paste the dependencies shown above into a `build.sbt` file in a freshly made empty directory and run `sbt update`, I don't get any such warning (from sbt 0.13.0).

Comment: Perhaps try `clean` and `reload` if you made some changes to the build file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Seth Tisue commented, sbt 0.13 should no longer display this warning. The behavior was considered a bug [#709](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/709) in sbt 0.12 and was fixed 9 months ago.